# Crystal report with formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula field (@stock) in my Crystal report, I want to put in this formula field

- Initial value = {Stock.ActualStock}
- {Stock.ActualStock} when {Delivry.Quantity} is null.
- (@stock) - {Delivry.Quantity} when {Delivry.Quantity} is not null

This is the code i tried:

```
    if IsNull({Delivry.Quantity}) Then
        formula = {Stock.ActualStock}
    Else
        formula = formula - {Delivry.Quantity}
    End If
```

But i get the vlue of {Delivry.Quantity} in (@stock) when {Delivry.Quantity}

it is not null, and when it is null i get this error message:

> Ce nom de champs est inconnu.
>   Erreur dans la formule de stock:
>   if IsNull({Delivry.Quantity}) Then

So how can i get the values i want in this formula field??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you translate the error message?

Comment: This field name is unknown, error in formula stock: if IsNull({Delivry.Quantity}) Then

Comment: are you sure field name is correct and you are using the correct database connection?

Comment: Yes i'm sure it is correct because when {Delivry.Quantity} is not null (@stock) return a value